# Python : 'float' object is not subscriptable (calculating distance from Prompt command)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and an exercise is to develop a script that from the windows command prompt calculates the distance from a city `-c` to `BH`. However, I have the following error:

```
cosseno = (sin(bh[0]*rad) * sin(lat[i]*rad)) + (cos(bh[0]*rad) * cos(lat[i]*rad) * cos((bh[1] - lon[i])*rad)) 

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried to convert the `BH` variable, I've tried to make changes but I always run into this error.

```
from math import cos, sin, acos
import sys

rad = float(3.14159/180.0) 
bh = [-20.15,-45.15]

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
  arg = sys.argv[i]
  if arg == '-c':
    cidade = sys.argv[i+1]
  elif arg == '-lat':
    lat = float(sys.argv[i+1])
  elif arg == '-lon':
    lon = float(sys.argv[i+1])

aaa = 0 
bbb = 0
for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)): 
    cosseno = (sin(bh[0]*rad) * sin(lat[i]*rad)) + (cos(bh[0]*rad) * cos(lat[i]*rad) * cos((bh[1] - lon[i])*rad))
    arco = acos(cosseno)/rad 
    dist = 111*arco
    print ('The distance between Belo Horizonte and', arg[cidade], 'it is', dist, 'km')
```

Comment: What's not clear from the error? `lat` and `lon` are floats so you can't do `lat[i]` or `lon[i]`

Comment: By the way, a side note - you should really look into [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). The way you're handling arguments is really cumbersome and unnecessary

Comment: Your first loop `for i in range(1, len(sys.argv))` loops over all command-line arguments and parses them; but why do you need a second such loop, below in the part where you do the actual calculation? That does not seem to make much sense.